# How can I redirect all subdomain to main domain with dns wildcard?

Tags: dns, subdomain, plesk

I want to redirect all subdomains like this:

test.website.com  to www.website.com.

I use IIS server with **shared IP** and PLESK control panel.

When I add a cname dns record like this: *.website.com  website.com
all subdomain redirected to IP of server and plesk default page is displayed!!

Are there any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Update for 2016*

IIS 10 in Windows 2016 supports [wildcard host header](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-10/wildcard-host-header-support) and you can create wildcard subdomains in **Plesk 17**.

*Origin answer*

You can set domain as default on IP address:
[image: plesk wildcard subdomain]

There is no ability to create wildcard subdomain on **IIS**: http://kb.parallels.com/en/2239

If you try to create wildcard binding on IIS website you will get:

```
---------------------------
Add Site Binding
---------------------------
The specified host name is incorrect. The host name must use a valid host name format and cannot contain the following characters: "/\[]:|<>+=;,?*$%#@{}^`. Example: www.contoso.com.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

So, plesk operates right - you create DNS record *.website.com but there is no virtual host which can serv such requests and they are fallback to default virtual host.